# Validating time-limited HMACs

Tags: security, authentication, hmac

I'm exploring using HMAC style secret-key authentication with timestamp expiry, but am struggling to get my head around how you validate the timestamp portion.

On the client side you would do:

```
my_hmac = hmac(my_secret, my_values)
```

Where you would have a `timestamp` field in `my_values`.

On the server (where you also know `my_secret`) you would attempt to rebuild the HMACd string with the request parameters:

```
my_hmac_to_compare = hmac(my_secret, my_values_from_http_request)
```

Is it simply a case of embedding the timestamp as a parameter so it's hashed in to the HMAC string and then ensuring the timestamp is within N minutes of when we process the request?

I have odd visions of having to iterate over 5 minutes worth of timestamps, rebuilding the HMAC string on the server attempting to find the needle-in-the-haystack that will generate the correct HMAC string.

**Bonus question:** Is there a consensus on how you would initially transfer the secret key to a client from a server?  It obviously becomes "dirty" after it goes over the wire, but in a user facing application you can't have someone pasting in an extensive secret key, especially if it's a mobile client.

Comment: Just add the timestamp in clear to the token. Something like `timestamp || HMAC(key, timestamp)`

Comment: For the larger problem: Why not simply throw SSL at the problem?

Comment: Have you solved this problem?